# How to call generic method

Tags: c#, .net, generics, automapper

I have two related models

**ModelBase.cs**

```
public class ModelBase
{
    public virtual ModelBase Map(DataRow dr)
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

**User.cs** which derives from above class. In the future I want to have more classes like user where I can map fields from DataRow to my properties

```
public class User : ModelBase
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public User() { }

    public override User Map(DataRow dr)
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration
            (cfg => cfg.CreateMap<DataRow, User>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(row => row["x"]))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(row => row["xx"]))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Surname, opt => opt.MapFrom(row => row["xxx"]))
        );

        var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
        return mapper.Map<User>(dr);
    }
}
```

I am receiving Users as **DataTable** so I have created simple method to convert it to list, but if there will be more classes (all received as DataTables), I want my function to be flexible and valid with rest of my models.
*The question is how can I use this dynamically?*

**Utility.cs**

```
public class DataTableConverter<T> where T : ModelBase
{
    public static List<T> ConvertToList(DataTable dt, Type type)
    {
        var results = new List<T>(dt.Rows.Count);
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
        // Here I want to call Map function from dynamic model and add it to results
        }
        return results;
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll need the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern (CRTP). To start you off: `public class ModelBase<T> where T : ModelBase<T>`, `public virtual T Map(DataRow dr)` and `public class User : ModelBase<User>`, then public class `DataTableConverter<T> where T : ModelBase<T>`

Comment: Automapper is a object-object mapper. When interfacing with a database you would typically use a Object-relational mapper (ORM), like Entity Framework.

Comment: I'm not interfacing with db, I am receiving datatables from external API

Comment: Your second problem however is the `// Here I want to call Map function from dynamic model and add it to results` -- `Map` is an instance method not a static method, so you'll need to create a new `User` instance in order to call `Map` on it, to create the `User` instance you actually want. You can do this with `where T : ModelBase<T>, new()`, and `new T().Map(...)`, but that's ugly and wasteful

Comment: If you're using AutoMapper, use it properly i.e. create `Profile` classes and use your `IMapper` directly.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

Make `ModelBase` abstract and generic and use the "Curiously Recurring Template Pattern" to enable you to define an abstract `Map()` method that returns the derived model types:

```
public abstract class ModelBase<T> where T : ModelBase<T>
{
    public abstract T Map(DataRow dr);
}
```

Then change `User` so that it is instead a `ModelBase<User>` (the `Map()` method remains unchanged):

```
public class User : ModelBase<User>
{
...
}
```

Your `DataTableConverter` needs to have a constraint that `T` is a `ModelBase<T>` and has a parameterless constructor (`new()`). The `ConvertToList()` method does not require a `Type` parameter to be specified - the type returned is determined by `T`:

```
public class DataTableConverter<T> where T : ModelBase<T>, new()
{
    public static List<T> ConvertToList(DataTable dt)
    {
        var results = new List<T>(dt.Rows.Count);
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            results.Add(new T().Map(row));
        }
        return results;
    }
}
```

As noted in the comments, the side effect of the above is that each row results in two model objects being created (one when `new T()` is called in `ConvertToList()`, and then the `Map()` method creates a new model object as a result of the mapping. It should be possible to avoid this duplication with a small change to the use of AutoMapper so that it populates the existing model object, rather than creating a new object:

```
    public static User Map(DataRow dr)
    {
        ...

        // Populate `this` with the data row, rather than creating a new `User`
        return mapper.Map(dr, this);
    }
```

Comment: "_The code you have included won't currently compile_", since C#9 it will, as covariant return types were introduced.

Comment: That aside, this design is flawed; should you really need to instantiate a `User`, simply to invoke an instance method that creates another `User`?

Comment: This is working but like @Johnathan said is there other way to call this method? I cant set **Map()** as **static** because it's also **overriden** or **abstract** in other models

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay - I've removed the comment regarding the return type. The design is based on minimal modification to the original code (which has `Map()` as an instance method). As you say, this is not ideal given the fact that the implementation in `User` returns a new instance, but it could be trivially updated to instead populate the instance rather than return a new instance.

Comment: @Bajojajo - I have made an edit to show how you can continue to call `Map()` as an instance method without unnecessarily creating additional model objects.

Comment: That's good idea to avoid creating too many instaces, but i'm getting error with this
`return mapper.Map(dr, this);`

Comment: @Bajojajo what is the error?

Answer (score 0):

@Iridium's answer describes how to use the CRTP to solve your issue, but has the wart that since `Map` is an instance method, you need to create a new, empty `User` instance in order to call `Map` on it, to get the `User` instance you actually want.

If you're using C# 10 (and .NET 6), you can make use of [static abstract interface methods](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/preview-features-in-net-6-generic-math/). You will probably need `<EnablePreviewFeatures>true</EnablePreviewFeatures>` in your csproj (and may also need `<LangVersion>preview</LangVersion>`).

This lets you write:

```
public interface IModelMapper<T> where T : IModelMapper<T>
{
    static abstract T Map(DataRow dr);  
}

public class User : IModelMapper<User>
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public User() { }

    public static User Map(DataRow dr)
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration
            (cfg => cfg.CreateMap<DataRow, User>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(row => row["x"]))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(row => row["xx"]))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Surname, opt => opt.MapFrom(row => row["xxx"]))
        );

        var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
        return mapper.Map<User>(dr);
    }
}

public class DataTableConverter<T> where T : IModelMapper<T>
{
    public static List<T> ConvertToList(DataTable dt, Type type)
    {
        var results = new List<T>(dt.Rows.Count);
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            results.Add(T.Map(row));
        }
        return results;
    }
}
```

See it on [dotnetfiddle.net](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NiSMlf).

Now, the `Map` method is static: you don't need to create a new `User` instance just to call `Map` on it.

---

If static abstract interface methods aren't available, you can get the same effect (but with a bit more boilerplate) by separating your concerns: split the `User` class from the class which does the mapping.

```
public class User
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public User() { }
}

public abstract class ModelMapper<T>
{
    public abstract T Map(DataRow dr);
}

public class UserModelMapper : ModelMapper<User>
{
    public static UserModelMapper Instance { get; } = new();
    public override User Map(DataRow dr)
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration
            (cfg => cfg.CreateMap<DataRow, User>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(row => row["x"]))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(row => row["xx"]))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Surname, opt => opt.MapFrom(row => row["xxx"]))
        );

        var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
        return mapper.Map<User>(dr);
    }
}
```

You then pass an instance of the right `ModelMapper` into `DataTableConverter`, and it's this mapper instance which does the conversion:

```
public static class DataTableConverter
{
    public static List<T> ConvertToList<T>(ModelMapper<T> mapper, DataTable dt, Type type)
    {
        var results = new List<T>(dt.Rows.Count);
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            results.Add(mapper.Map(row));
        }
        return results;
    }
}
```

See it on [dotnetfiddle.net](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0JJXB9).

Comment: Hmm... I am getting **static element cannot be marked as abstract, override, virtual**

Comment: @Bajojajo Are you using C#10?

Comment: Are you using C# 10? You'll probably also need to enable preview features, see my edit